# cakephp 3.x save deep associations

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Following models with conventional tables in cakephp 3:

books *--belongsTo-->* publishers *<--habtm-->* groupnumbers

In the view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('isbn');
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('writer');
echo $this->Form->input('price', ['type' => 'number']);
echo $this->Form->input('publisher_id', ['options' => $publishers]);
echo $this->Form->input('publisher.groupnumbers.0.number');
```

Controller:

```
$associations = ['associated' =>[
        'Publishers',
        'Publishers.Groupnumbers'
    ]
];
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $book = $this->Books->patchEntity($book, $this->request->data, $associations);
    if ($this->Books->save($book)){
        //do something
    } else {
        //do somethin else
         debug ($book->errors());
    }
}
```

This the save methode returns false and the error is

> 'publisher' => [        'name' => [             '_required' => 'This field is
>   required'         ]   ]

Why asks cakephp me for the publisher_name?I do not create a new publisher here and the publisher_id is linking to an existing one. It works perfectly if I don't want to save the groupnumber. 
What's wrong with this code?

Edit:
I tried

```
$data['publisher']['id'] = $this->request->data['publisher_id'];
// and $data['publisher.id'] = $this->request->data['publisher_id'];
unset($data['publisher_id']);
$book = $this->Books->patchEntity($book, $data, $associations);
```

But this does't change anything.

Comment: `$this->Form->input('publisher.g` <- You are defining your form fields as if you are updating the field groupnumbers on the publisher model - that'll attempt to create a new publisher. What is it you're actually trying to do - i.e. what is that input for?

Comment: I try to  add a groupnumber (if it does not already exist) to an existing publisher.